# gtag / google_tag_manager confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, next.js

I am using Google Analytics to track custom events in my react application. When I first rolled out the code, I read [this document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration), suggesting use of `gtag` method instead of `ga` method to make the logging calls. This has been working fine.

I am using Google Tag Manager, so these scripts are all loaded via GTM (presumably).

Now I'm doing something a bit trickier, the server needs to tell the client to log on page load in a particular case. So I have adapted the GTM initialization code such that an event fires once GTM has loaded. I read how to do that [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/notify-page-google-tag-manager-loaded/).

The strange thing is that when the callback indicating the GTM library has loaded fires `gtag` is not defined and the code to log an event in Analytics fails. By the time I can type `gtag` in the browser console it's defined, so perhaps the GTM script is loading it secondarily?

```
if (!!window.google_tag_manager) {
  // Google Tag Manager has already been loaded
  doSomethingWith(window.google_tag_manager);
} else {
  window.addEventListener('gtm_loaded', function() {
    //----------------------------------------
    // Google Tag Manager has been loaded, but
    // gtag object is not defined :(
    //----------------------------------------
  });
}
```

Is there some other way to log Analytics events with the `google_tag_manager` object? Or, is there a way to know when the `gtag` object is available short of polling (really want to avoid that)?

This is the code I'm using to load GTM

```
class InitDataLayer extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.dataLayer = [{
            appName: 'promos',
        }];
    }
    render = () => (<script id="init-data-layer" />)
}

class LoadGtm extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        (function(w,d,s,l,i) {
            w[l]=w[l]||[];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event:'gtm.js'
            });
            var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),
                dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
                j.async=true;
                j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
                f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);

            j.addEventListener('load', () => {
                const _ge = new CustomEvent('gtm_loaded', { bubbles: true });
                d.dispatchEvent(_ge);
            });
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');
    }
    render = () => (<script id="load-gtm" />)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create google analytics events in the google tag manager interface. This does not require additional coding. See reference https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107124?hl=en

Comment: I don't like the idea of having one of the several events implemented in the GTM interface. Surely there is a way to achieve this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I realized `gtag` is defined in GTM! I then adapted the tag with the approach outlined in my question to fire a custom event indicating when `gtag` is available:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXX', {send_page_view: false});
  var _ge = new CustomEvent('gtag_loaded', { bubbles: true });
  document.dispatchEvent(_ge);
</script>
```

Now in the client code

```
if(typeof gtag !== 'undefined') {
    gaSendEvent(event);
} else {
    window.addEventListener('gtag_loaded', () => {
        gaSendEvent(event);
    });
}
```